# Resizing an svg image that is used like a component through media query

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries

I am working with svg images and I need to change their height and width properties for certain screen sizes.

I am using them as components. For example:

```html
<Doc className="img" />
```

That is an svg element:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="758" height="865" viewBox="0 0 758 865">
  <image id="Doc6" width="758" height="865" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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</svg>
```

But if I assign a class to them, it has no effect on their dimensions:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1400px) {    
  .img {
    height: 720px;
    width: 720px;
  }
}
```

What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML? Right now we have no way to test this.

Comment: Do you mean the svg tag?

Comment: If you want the svg to resize, then you shouldn't hardcode width and height as svg attributes, then. `width="758" height="865"`

Comment: @HåkenLid if I remove those values in svg.file, the image disappears.

Comment: I can't make that any value I put in .js file be taken by the svg images

Comment: You can use relative size `100%` to make the svg fill space inside the parent node.

Comment: Sorry, @HåkenLid I don't follow you :(. Could you write it on?